# R - change values in multiple selected rows based on multiple conditional column

Tags: r, dplyr

In SAS data step it is easy and intuitive to change value of selected row and column based on conditions. For example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  if col1 = "A" and col2 = "B" then do;
    col3 = "C";
    col4 = catx(",", Col1, Col2);
  end;
run;
```

I want to do the same thing in R. I have the following:

```
want <- have %>%
  mutate(
    col3 = ifelse(col1 == "A" & col2 == "B", "C", col3),
    col4 = ifelse(col1 == "A" & col2 == "B", paste(col1, col2, sep = ","))
  )
```

If I have more than 1 column need to change, I have to repeat the ifelse() for each column I want to change.

Is there a easier way to do it?

Thanks

=====================================

I tried this:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(have)) { 
    if (have$col1 == "A" & have$col2 == "B") { 
        have$col3 = 'C' 
        have$col4 = paste(have$col1, have$col2, sep=",") 
    } 
}
```

However, mydataset is too big to loop through.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple condition if-else using dplyr, custom function, or purr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028764/multiple-condition-if-else-using-dplyr-custom-function-or-purr)

Comment: I have few combined condition to select certain rows and columns, after that I will apply changes to all the selected rows.
I can achieve it by use for-loop to fetch all the rows, then use condition to see if the row satisfy the condition. If so, I can make the change to the selected row. However, my dataset is too big to do the for-loop.
```
for (row in 1:nrow(mydataset)){
  if (mydataset$col1 %in% c(7626312, 7531913, 8330834, 7875276)) {
    mydataset$col2 = '07'
    mydataset$col3 = "3895"
    mydataset$col4 = "NY"
    mydataset$col5 = 6420050
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your examples, provide a reproducible data set and expected results? It will help people help you. In your first example, you are missing the FALSE condition for col4 so that code couldn't have worked for you. And in your for loop, you are not using "row" so that couldn't have worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative way without loop:

```
have <- have %>% mutate(cond = col1 == "A" & col2 == "B", id = 1:nrow(have))
met  <- have %>% filter(cond == TRUE) %>% 
        mutate(col3 = "C", col4 = paste(cyl, hp, sep = ","))
have[met$id,] <- met
```

Comment: I see. 2 steps: first mark down all the rows satisfied the condition. Then filter those rows and make change to target columns. Wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to save the condition in a column and use it for different columns.

```
library(dplyr)

want <- have %>%
  mutate(
    condition = col1 == "A" & col2 == "B",
    col3 = ifelse(condition, "C", col3),
    col4 = ifelse(condition, paste(col1, col2, sep = ","), col4)
  )
```

Comment: I've thought about it. I still need to repeat the ifelse() part for each column (like col3, col4...) I want to make change. The SAS version use the conditional if-else wrap around the operation part.

Comment: My understanding is SAS data step fetch in each row one at a time, then process it and moving on to the next row. So using if-else wrap around operation part makes more sense. 

R, on the other hand, treat columns as whole. So make change on columns, or select column/row by condition is much faster than SAS. But make change on a particular cell (selected row and column) is hard.